# MySQL: Given a row and multiple strings. Find the string(s) that are contained in the row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I've got (e.g.) the following MySQL row:

```
firstname | lastname | anotherCol1 | anotherCol2 | anotherCol3
--------------------------------------------------------------
John      | Smith    | Football    | Fast cars   | 18 Fools
```

and for instance the following strings:

```
oh, xxx, foo, 41
```

I am looking for a statement that returns `oh` and `foo`, because the rows cells do contain these substrings (`oh`: J*oh*n, `foo`: *Foo*tball & *Foo*ls).

Comment: Can you elaborate your question with clearance detials?

Comment: And also: What have you tried?

Comment: Select everything, then iterate over the results and mark the matches?

Comment: What are the reasons `php` tag is included?

Comment: Sorry, this is my very first post on Stack Overflow. Which details are missing? I did not try anything yet, because things I know like `SELECT * WHERE col LIKE %foo%` won't work (obviously). I've never used a statement like I'm looking for now.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius I'm going to implement it in PHP, however, that is not necessary for the solution right now.

Comment: @ATaylor ok thanks, that would work. I just asked myself whether there is a way to do this in one MySQL statement. Maybe I've expected to much ;)

Comment: There may be a way to do this purely in mySQL as some of the other answers suggest. My answer deals with a PHP solution, in case you should decide to opt for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution

```sql
SELECT q.keyword
  FROM Table1 t CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT 'oh' keyword UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xxx' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'foo' UNION ALL
  SELECT '41'
) q
 WHERE INSTR(CONCAT_WS(' ', firstname, 
                            lastname, 
                            anotherCol1, 
                            anotherCol2), q.keyword) > 0
```

Output:

```
| KEYWORD |
-----------
|      oh |
|     foo |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0fefc/2)** demo

Comment: Great, that looks awesome.  Thank you!
I'm not an expert on this topic yet, however, I'll try to comprehend how your statement works.

Answer (score 0):

If your table is `MyISAM`, you can make use of [Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Create an `index` on your table with the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> ADD FULLTEXT(firstname, lastname, anotherCol1, anotherCol2, anotherCol3 );
```

Now, run your queries (Use `boolean` mode as you have to match on multiple keywords):

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE MATCH(firstname, lastname, anotherCol1, anotherCol2, anotherCol3) AGAINST ('+oh +xxx +foo +41' IN BOOLEAN MODE );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I fear that this statement will find a row that contains the given keywords. Unfortunately I would like to get the keywords that are contained by a specific row (I'm not sure, whether my explanation is clear enough…)

Answer (score 0):

It's mainly a question of whom you want to take the brunt of the workload.
In my solution, I'll opt for PHP taking it, simply because a database is for querying data, but not for calculating or processing it.

Now,  first things first, you'll fetch all data from your database.

```
SELECT * FROM table;
```

Nothing more, nothing less. This will return you every single column and every single row in the table. Now for the PHP part.

```
<?php 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        foreach($row as $header => $col) {
            foreach($strings as $str) {
                if(strstr($col, $str) !== false) {
                    echo "$str found in column $header";
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I hope this helps a little.

Comment: What if there are a lot of rows? In my opinion, this should be done in mysql only.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius As I said, it depends on who should take the brunt of the calculative power. And I'm not mySQL-savy enough to come up with anything clever enough to do it on the database level. I'm just stating an option...though filter criteria would most certainly help, yes. But fortunately, there are already multiple other answers around, which help out with the filtering.